# Why can't Huggingface's Transformers module load models from custom cache in Docker container's volume?

Tags: python-3.x, docker, huggingface-transformers

I understand that huggingface prefers to load models from the internet. However, I have a machine that doesn't have access to the internet. So, I am trying to load a model from its cached files, which I have moved to a custom directory `/tmp/models/huggingface_cache`. I have a volume for the container to access these files, and I have verified the container has access.

What I don't understand is why huggingface wants to create a directory to manage cache when I specified a custom directory first. The volume access should remain as read only. Therefore, I'm curious why I'm having these issues, and whether there is a better route to workaround huggingface's functionality of loading cached models.

I'm running an interactive container built from Ubuntu with the following command:

```bash
docker run -it --rm -v /tmp:/tmp:rw generic-container /bin/bash
```

I then run the following commands in python3:

```py
from transformers import pipeline
from os import environ

environ["TRANSFORMERS_OFFLINE"] = "1"
environ["TRANSFORMERS_CACHE"] = "/tmp/models/huggingface_cache"

classifier = pipeline("zero-shot-classification", model="facebook/bart-large-mnli", cache_dir="/tmp/models/huggingface_cache")
```

And I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/transformers/pipelines/__init__.py", line 645, in pipeline
    config = AutoConfig.from_pretrained(model, _from_pipeline=task, **hub_kwargs, **model_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/transformers/models/auto/configuration_auto.py", line 809, in from_pretrained
    config_dict, unused_kwargs = PretrainedConfig.get_config_dict(pretrained_model_name_or_path, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/transformers/configuration_utils.py", line 559, in get_config_dict
    config_dict, kwargs = cls._get_config_dict(pretrained_model_name_or_path, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/transformers/configuration_utils.py", line 614, in _get_config_dict
    resolved_config_file = cached_file(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/transformers/utils/hub.py", line 409, in cached_file
    resolved_file = hf_hub_download(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/huggingface_hub/utils/_validators.py", line 124, in _inner_fn
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/huggingface_hub/file_download.py", line 1038, in hf_hub_download
    os.makedirs(storage_folder, exist_ok=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 213, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 213, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 213, in makedirs
    makedirs(head, exist_ok=exist_ok)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/os.py", line 223, in makedirs
    mkdir(name, mode)
PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/.cache'
```

Comment: In the Dockerfile, I set `USER 12345`. After removing this and the above references to cache_dir (environment variables and function parameter) the model was loaded perfectly fine. I'm assuming my issue had to do with permissions of `USER 12345`

Comment: can you run something like `chown -R 12345:12345 /tmp/models/huggingface_cache` or some other way to give USER 12345 permissions to read/write the custom cache directory? [more info here](https://www.baeldung.com/ops/root-user-password-docker-container)